# How to configure twitter button in Bookdown?

Tags: r, knitr, bookdown

I would like to know how to configure twitter button in bookdown's gitbook output format.

I couldn´t find the answer in [*Authoring Books and Technical Documents with R Markdown*](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/)

Comment: You mean here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html#gitbook-style ..?

Comment: Hi @gitzhuoer, I really thanks for your help but I still couldn't solve my problem. I understand your answer but once I configure the buttons to appear, where should I have to specify the url? If I press the twitter button in my bookdown nothing happens.

Comment: You need to open your book with a browser, such as Chrome, not RStudio. And you don't need to specify the url, you will be redirected to the twitter login webpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html#gitbook-style

```
bookdown::gitbook:
    config:
        sharing:
        facebook: yes
        twitter: yes
        google: no
        weibo: no
        instapper: no
        vk: no
        all: ['facebook', 'google', 'twitter', 'weibo', 'instapaper']
```

> On the right of the toolbar, there are some buttons to share the link on social network websites such as Twitter, Facebook, and Google+. You can use the `sharing` option to decide which buttons to enable. If you want to get rid of these buttons entirely, use `sharing: null` (or `no`).

Here is a minimal example:

`index.Rmd`

````
---
title: "A Book"
author: "Frida Gomam"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output:
  bookdown::gitbook: 
    config: 
      sharing:
        twitter: yes
---

# reference

This is my table \@ref(tab:mytable)

# table

```{r mytable, echo=TRUE}
knitr::kable(iris[1:10, ], booktabs=T, caption='A table of the first 10 rows of the mtcars data')
```
````

[image]
[image]